# EFI or BIOS in intel atom??.

Tags: bios, efi

I have an intel atom with fedora on it.I see efi config file in /boot/efi/EFI/redhat ,but efi config file specifies that it is a dos/windows application.

I used dmidecode cmd and  found out that  that system still uses BIOS.Here s the output

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 0, 24 bytes

BIOS Information

```
Vendor: Intel Corp.

Version: DPP3510J.86A.0216.2007.0502.1916

Release Date: 05/02/2007

Address: 0xF0000
     ....

     ....
```

I am not able understand what is actually starting the system BIOS or efi .Also since efi is relatively new can someone suggest where to start of, since i want to write application in efi which i believe is in c language

Comment: Hopefully helpful: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-grub-whatis-booting-uefi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFI - Extensible Firmware Interface is now advanced to UEFI.

All implementations are in C only as you thought.

Refer [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI)

To start work in UEFI

1. Download the EDK2 Tree from [SF.net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tianocore/index.php?title=EDK2) and follow the instruction.
   There is a edk2 developers forum. For UEFI Specifications, plz go to [UEFI.org](http://www.uefi.org/)